# Right button not appearing on modal view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to add a button to a modal view controller so it can be dismised but the button is not displaying. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
UIViewController* webView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController* modalViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:webView];
[webView release];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(hideModalView)];
modalViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
[doneButton release];

[globalNavController presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this.

```
webView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the doneButton to your `UIViewController`, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change webView to webViewController, a better name.